# Push and pop on react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

i have this react state in mi component

```
    this.state =
    {
        Preferences: []
    }
```

and i want to push only if the element not exists because i dont want the same repeated element, and i want to pop the element if is already exists this is the function what i use

```
    SelectPreference = Id =>
{
    
    if(!this.state.Preferences.includes(Id))
    {
        this.setState(state => 
        {
            const Preferences = state.Preferences.concat(Id);
       
            return {
                Preferences,
            };
        });

    }
    else
    {
        this.setState(state => 
        {
            const Preferences = state.Preferences.filter(Item => Item !== Id);
       
            return {
                Preferences,
            };
        });
    }
    console.log(this.state.Preferences);

}
```

the problem is when i push a object it says the array is empty and when i pop the element it says i have a element. i dont kwon how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as the following if you want your preferences to be uniq.

Based on your code, I understand that id is a string. Tell me if it's not the case.

For [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) about Set and uniq value in array

```js
if(!this.state.Preferences.includes(Id)) {
  this.setState(state => ({
    // Using a set will make sure your id is uniq
    Preferences: [...new Set([...state.Preferences, id])]
  }))
} 
else {
  this.setState(state => ({
    // You're code was good, I only change syntax
    Preferences: state.Preferences.filter(Item => Item !== Id)
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. It will be pretty hard to immediately check the updated `this.state.Preferences` in the same function block.

Still if you need to check the updated value of the `Preferences`, you can provide a callback which will be executed immediately after change in state.

```
this.setState({ Preferences }, () => console.log(this.state))
```

Also, there is simpler version of your logic.

```
if(this.state.Preferences.includes(Id)) {
    this.setState({
        Preferences: this.state.Preferences.filter(id => id !== Id);
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        Preferences: this.state.Preferences.concat(Id);
    });
}
```